# how do I handle this messy variable shadowing?

Tags: java, oop

I have a `SharedFolder` class that implements an abstract `Endpoint` class, the problem is related to one of the attributes of the subclass (`baseDir`) that depends on the value of another attribute (`environment`) that gets updated after the instantiation of the class, here's what I'm talking about:

```
public class SharedFolderEndpoint extends Endpoint {

    private String name = "SharedFolder";
    private String hostname = "somehostname";
    private Environment environment;
    private String baseDir;
    private String format = "someformat"
    private String pattern = "somepattern";

    public SharedFolderEndpoint() {

    }
    ...
```

The basedir path depends on the value of the environment, the variable needs to be initialized with something like this:

```
this.baseDir= "/env-"+this.environment+"/somefolder/files";
```

The class is instantiated by the GUI and then the user has to pick the environment he/she wants to interact with, so, as you can see, prior to this manual interaction `this.environment` references a `null` value.

I wonder if there would be an elegant solution to update this value without creating a new method to append the value to the path. Any ideas?

Comment: It's a pretty open ended question because it really depends on how the `baseDir` value is being used. If it's only used rarely and only needs to be valid at some later point, there's no reason not to just calculate it on the fly. If it needs to be valid and used right away, you'll need some way to provide a legit default value. If it's used frequently, you'll want to calculate it only when needed and save the calculated value. There are tons of ways to do this depending on these options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a variant to Taks answer (1+ to it), you could make baseDir a "calculated" property that is built from a constant format String, so that the skeleton of the String is available for quick review as a constant, something like:

```
public class SharedFolderEndpoint extends Endpoint {
   private static final String BASEDIR_FORMAT = "/env-%s/somefolder/files";
   //...


   // might need to declare this as throwing the exception
   public String getBaseDir() {  
      if (environment.isPopulated()) {
        return String.format(BASEDIR_FORMAT, environment.toString());
      } else {
        // throw an exception...
      }
   }
}
```

This example shows just it being created with just one String variable, `%s`, but it would be trivial to add more.

For example if you want to use a folder variable and files variable, you could do:

```
public class SharedFolderEndpoint extends Endpoint {
   private static final String BASEDIR_FORMAT = "/env-%s/%s/%s";
   //...


   // might need to declare this as throwing the exception
   public String getBaseDir() {  
      if (!environment.isPopulated()) {
        // ... throw exception showing no environment
      } else {
      if (!folder.isPopulated()) {
        // ... throw exception showing no folder
      } else {
      if (!file.isPopulated()) {
        // ... throw exception showing no file
      } else {
        // throw an exception...
        return String.format(BASEDIR_FORMAT, 
               environment.getText(),
               folder.getText(),
               files.getText());
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could store environment in separate variable and have a method that lazly loads the basedir path:

```
   public void setEnvironment(Environment environment)
   {
        this.environment=environment;
        baseDir = null;
   }


   public String getBaseDir() {
       if(baseDir==null)
           "/env-"+this.environment+"/somefolder/files";
       return baseDir
   }
```

if environment variable would be changed really often you could use StringBuilder and again caching value. Also you could use StringFormat to make concat look pretty. If one instance of SharedFolderEndpoint is shared between all users you could create some sort of map userId->Path.

Comment: This works but.. it kind of introduces a problem in my API, what if someone populates `baseDir` but not the `environment` variable? What if I want to reuse this code somewhere else?

Comment: It would be not possible to evaluate baseDir if environment variable is not set. In this case you could have some default value or throw exception or return null. The behaviour there is entirely up to you really. What kind of reusing are we talking about?